# Redirect user from login page

Tags: django

When the user presses on login, nothing happens. I would like to redirect them to calculator.html where i intend to make some entry fields to obtain parameters from the user to calculate a certain value at the end.

Django 1.11.11
Python 3.6.4

Thanks.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('webapp.urls')),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # log the user in
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/calculator/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', { 'form': form })


@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def calculator(request):
    return render(request, 'webapp/calculator.html')
```

app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^calculator/$', views.calculator, name='calculator'),
    url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='login', permanent=False)),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'webapp/base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <form class="site-form" action="/registration/login" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

calculator.html

```
{% extends 'webapp/base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1><a href="/">calculator bla bla</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I am very new to Django so thanks again.

Comment: Note that you could use the built in [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) instead of writing your own. If you set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'calculator'` in your settings, then users will be redirected to the calculator URL after they have logged in.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks, i just ended up doing that

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your code:

Your form is posting to a different URL than `/login/`:

```
<form class="site-form" action="/registration/login" method="post">
```

Your catch-all redirect is probably confusing matters. I would remove it:

```
url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='login', permanent=False)),
```

You should change the indentation at the end of your view so that you return a response for invalid views:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', { 'form': form })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = dict()
    form = ControlLoginForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
        username = user.username
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            logout(request)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Welcome back %s' % user.first_name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("Your URL")
        else:
            context = dict()
            context['not_user'] = True
            return render(request, "home.html", context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Try using Class Based Views. In that overwrite def post method.